# Update multiple contents in single commit with Octokit

Tags: ruby, github, octokit

I see we can update a file from the by [Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb)'s [#update_contents method](http://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Contents.html#update_contents-instance_method). This will update one file with new content in one commit.

Is there a way to update multiple contents in single commit via GitHub API with Octokit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to do that, the low-level [Git Data API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/).

But need to make multiple API requests (to create the required blobs, trees, commits and update the ref), the flexibility in that API allows you to group changes in single commit or as many commits as you want.

Here is [a tutorial](https://github.com/jollygoodcode/jollygoodcode.github.io/issues/14).